# Initializing Enum variable in abstract class

Tags: java, class, service, enums, abstract-class

I'm supposed to initialize et to NONE but I keep getting an error.
The error that keeps popping up says "CANNOT FIND SYMBOL." I really have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Any help guys?

```
public abstract class Worker
{
public String name;
public int socialSecurity;
private int yearsExperience;
public Jobs et = null;
public static int id;
public int currentID;

public Worker ()
{
    name = "AnyName";
    socialSecurity = 12345;
    yearsExperience = 0;
    et = NONE;
    id++;
    currentID = id;
}

public Worker (String n, int ss, int ye, Jobs j)
{
    id++;
    currentID = id;
    name = n;
    socialSecurity = ss;
    yearsExperience = ye;
    et = j;
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public int getSocialSecurity()
{
    return socialSecurity;
}

public int yearsExperience()
{
    return yearsExperience;
}

public Jobs getJobs()
{
    return et;
}

public void setName(String n1)
{
    name = n1;
}

public void setSocialSecurity(int ss1)
{
    socialSecurity = ss1;
}

public void setYearsExperience(int ye1)
{
    yearsExperience = ye1;
}

public void setJobs(Jobs et1)
{
    et = et1;
}

public abstract double benefitsCalculation(Jobs et2);
}
```

Below is my enum class

```
public enum Jobs {ELECTRICAL_ENGINEER, MECHANICAL_ENGINEER, ADMINISTRATIVE_SECRETARY, ADMINISTRATIVE_ASSISTAN, ENGINEERING_MANAGER, ADMINISTRATIVE_MANAGER, NONE};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that:

```
et = Jobs.NONE;
```

and be sure that you import `Jobs` if it's no in the same package.

Comment: OH MY GOD! wow why didn't I think of trying this before. Major face palm. Thank you so much! :D it worked